# Adding specific list-elements in a pandas column of lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe where one column consists of lists:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]})
```

I want to add, e.g., the first and last index of each list. For that I use `apply`:

```
df['a'].apply(lambda x: x[0] + x[-1])
```

This acts on each row individually, which can be quite intensive if the dataframe is large. Is there a way to vectorize this operation?

Comment: Use `df.iloc[:, 0]+df.iloc[:, -1]`

Comment: @jezrael Please see OP. Sorry, I made an error (again!) when formulating my question.. now it should be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df.iloc[0]+df.iloc[-1]
a     4
b    10
c    16
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks. I was very unclear in my OP, I apologize for that - I need `axis=1` (please see updated post)